# How to integrate MyScript into Electron for offline handwriting recognition?

Tags: javascript, electron, cross-platform, progressive-web-apps, shape-recognition

I'm trying to integrate MyScript into my Electron application to enable offline handwriting recognition. I would like to know how to achieve this.

If it's not possible to directly integrate MyScript into Electron, I would like to know if it's possible to deploy a local server provided by MyScript for communication between the Electron process and the local server.

I'm looking for guidance on how to use MyScript for handwriting recognition in Electron or any solution for deploying a local MyScript server and communicating with it from my Electron application.

I tried using MyScript's cloud service for handwriting recognition, but it only supports online recognition and does not offer offline recognition capabilities.